# Protractor: "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Tags: request, promise, protractor

I am using Node's 'request' module to make 2 http requests for a unit test. I have to make sure 1 is carried out before the other and am trying to do so using a promise, but am getting the error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". Below is the function where the error is occuring:

```
this.setupSpec = function () {
    var deleteItemsRepo = deleteRepo(strings.editRepo);
    deleteItemsRepo.then(function () {
        createRepo(strings.editRepo);
    }); //todo: this must complete before createRepo starts, npm install async?
    //createRepo(strings.editRepo);
    return deleteItemsRepo; //return promise
};
```

deleteRepo(...) and createRepo(...) are just functions that call http requests.

Here is deleteRepo():

```
var deleteRepo = function (repoName) {
        return request.delete(browser.params.baseRestUrl + 'repositories/' + repoName,
        {'auth': browser.params.auth}, function (e, r, user) {
            console.log("Status code of deleteRepo('" + repoName + "'): " + r.statusCode);
        });
};
```

Comment: clearly the problem is that `deleteRepo` function returns undefined (or no return statement) - so the code for `deleteRepo` is where the problem actually lies

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried returning the status code at the end of deleteRepo(), but still got the same error

Comment: `I tried returning the status code` ... yes, I can see in my crystal ball what you did ... not ... clearly the problem is with `deleteRepo` code ... how about you post that so that we can tell you what you are doing wrong. If you are returning something, and still getting `undefined` returned, you're actually **not** returning anything

Comment: @JaromandaX I've added the deleteRepo function

Comment: `request.delete` doesn't look like it returns a Promise ... in fact, it probably returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deleteRepo` would return a Promise only if `request.delete` returns a Promise - which seems unlikely considering it uses a callback

"promisify" `deleteRepo` as follows for fun and profit

```
var deleteRepo = function(repoName) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request.delete(browser.params.baseRestUrl + 'repositories/' + repoName, {'auth': browser.params.auth}, function(e, r, user) {
            console.log("Status code of deleteRepo('" + repoName + "'): " + r.statusCode);
            if(e) {
                return reject(e);
            }
            resolve(r.statusCode);
        });
    });
};
```